# How to fix find record exists

Tags: php, laravel

I get a problem when I want to use it directly and if it is on the controller

```
if(Promosi::where('kode',$kodepromo)->count() > 0):
        $tambah = new Invoice();
        $tambah->id_user = $request['id_user'];
        $tambah->id = $id;
        $tambah->id_invoice = $request['id_invoice'];
        $tambah->item = 'Discout for Vendor';
        $tambah->category = $kode->type;
        $tambah->price = $potongan;
        $tambah->type = 'debit';
        $tambah->save();
        return redirect()->to('/bill/'.$id);   
    else:         
        return redirect()->to('/bill/'.$id);   
    endif;
```

> 1/1) ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object in HomeController.php line 469 at HandleExceptions -> handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'D:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php', 469, array('request' => object(Request), 'id' => 'a5804090-d97f-421b-8e38-6eddc02f4d62', 'kodepromo' => 'ffff', 'kode' => null, 'themebill' => object(Invoice), 'price' => '150000'))in HomeController.php line 469

Comment: Do you recieve any error messages?

Comment: ` (1/1) ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object
in HomeController.php line 469
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myfolder\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController.php', 469, array('request' => object(Request), 'id' => 'a5804090-d97f-421b-8e38-6eddc02f4d62', 'kodepromo' => 'ffff', 'kode' => null, 'themebill' => object(Invoice), 'price' => '150000'))in HomeController.php line 469`

Answer (score 0):

If you are set an `id` manualy, eloquent ORM cant see this, and trying to create a new record. To change this behavior set your `$tambah->exists` to true, then save.

```
$tambah->exists = true;
$tambah->save();
```

If `$tambah->exists` is true, ORM going to use MySQL `update`, else it going to use MySQL `insert`